# Foreach stops finding dynamically created controls after some amount of time. Resizing window makes it work again. Why? How can I fix it?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm a fairly new c# programmer currently in class and I've been doing this side project that (kind of) accurately represents bouncing balls. I also want it to be able to handle balls that are created on mouse click. I've done all of this and it works, for a few seconds. The original ball always works and always bounces/rolls. Dynamically created balls that are created on mouse click will hop and roll for a little but then they all freeze(not all at the same time) as the foreach statement I use stops recognizing that they are there. Weirdly enough when the window is resized using the bottom they start to work again. Am I missing something or is this a bug I can't fix? Here's the form code and the designer code. If you need anything else let me know.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace testBouncingBallMulti
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const int INITY = 0;
        const int INITX = 3;
        const int GRAVITY = 1;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.ball0.Tag = new Point(INITX, INITY);
        }

        byte counter = 1;

        private void createBall(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            Label l = new Label();
            l.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            l.Location = new Point(MousePosition.X - this.Left, MousePosition.Y - this.Top);
            this.Controls.Add(l);
            l.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(15, 15);
            l.Tag = new Point(INITX, INITY);
            l.Name = "ball" + Convert.ToString(counter);
            counter++;
        }

        private void physicsLoop1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (var ball in this.Controls.OfType<Label>())
            {
                moveBall(ball);
                bounce(ball);

                Point? init = ball.Tag as Point?;
                Point velocities = init.GetValueOrDefault(new Point(0, 0));
                if (velocities.Y == 0 && ball.Location.Y >= ClientSize.Height - 15)
                {
                    return;
                }
                velocities.Y = velocities.Y + GRAVITY;

                ball.Tag = new Point(velocities.X, velocities.Y);
            }
        }



        private void moveBall(Control ball)
        {
            Point? init = ball.Tag as Point?;
            Point velocities = init.GetValueOrDefault(new Point(0,0));

            ball.Location = new Point(ball.Location.X + velocities.X, ball.Location.Y + velocities.Y);
        }

        private void bounce(Control ball)
        {
            Point? init = ball.Tag as Point?;
            Point velocities = init.GetValueOrDefault(new Point(0,0));

            if (ball.Location.Y >= ClientSize.Height - 15)
            {
                if (velocities.Y == 0 && ball.Location.Y >= ClientSize.Height - 15)
                {
                }
                else if (ball.Location.Y > ClientSize.Height - 15)
                {
                    ball.Location = new Point(ball.Location.X, ClientSize.Height - 15);
                    velocities.Y = -(velocities.Y - 2);
                }
            }

            if (ball.Location.X >= ClientSize.Width - 15)
            {
                velocities.X = -(velocities.X);
            }

            if (ball.Location.X <= 0)
            {
                ball.Location = new Point(0, ball.Location.Y);
                velocities.X = -(velocities.X);
            }

            ball.Tag = new Point(velocities.X, velocities.Y);
        }

        private void physicsLoop2(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void physicsLoop3(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

and the designer code:

```
namespace testBouncingBallMulti
{
    partial class Form1
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        private System.ComponentModel.IContainer components = null;

        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="disposing">true if managed resources should be disposed; otherwise, false.</param>
        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing && (components != null))
            {
                components.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        #region Windows Form Designer generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InitializeComponent()
        {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            this.timer1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.ball0 = new System.Windows.Forms.Label();
            this.timer2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.timer3 = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer(this.components);
            this.SuspendLayout();
            // 
            // timer1
            // 
            this.timer1.Enabled = true;
            this.timer1.Interval = 20;
            this.timer1.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.physicsLoop1);
            // 
            // ball0
            // 
            this.ball0.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
            this.ball0.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 24);
            this.ball0.Name = "ball0";
            this.ball0.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(15, 15);
            this.ball0.TabIndex = 0;
            // 
            // timer2
            // 
            this.timer2.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.physicsLoop2);
            // 
            // timer3
            // 
            this.timer3.Tick += new System.EventHandler(this.physicsLoop3);
            // 
            // Form1
            // 
            this.AutoScaleDimensions = new System.Drawing.SizeF(6F, 13F);
            this.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font;
            this.ClientSize = new System.Drawing.Size(504, 396);
            this.Controls.Add(this.ball0);
            this.Name = "Form1";
            this.Text = "Form1";
            this.MouseClick += new System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventHandler(this.createBall);
            this.ResumeLayout(false);

        }

        #endregion

        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer1;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Label ball0;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer2;
        private System.Windows.Forms.Timer timer3;
    }
}
```

Comment: `this.timer1.Interval = 20;`  Your interval is too fast; you're definitely saturating your message pump.  Increase that to at least 50.  You may even want to turn `timer1` **off** at the beginning of `physicsLoop1()`, then turn it back **on** at the bottom.  I agree with Jacob, `return` is probably not what you want there.  Instead of using `this.Controls.OfType<Label>()`, maintain your own `List<Label>` and iterate over that.

Comment: Have you tried Jacob's solution yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `return` with `continue` in

```
if (velocities.Y == 0 && ball.Location.Y >= ClientSize.Height - 15)
{
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thank you this worked, and I feel like an idiot for not realizing it earlier. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score -1):

You need to give some breathing room in your label move procedure to repaint the form. Either use best practice and place your painting into a thread or at least process a windows message or two in your timer loop.

Comment: I just tested your Application.DoEvents() solution and it still ends in the same outcome with all of the non original labels freezing. What do you mean by the painting?

Comment: Please never ever use `Application.DoEvents()`. It's only in the .NET framework for backward compatibility for VB6 apps. `DoEvents` can cause all sorts of re-entrancy issues and should be avoided to avoid introducing bugs.

Comment: When you add a new control to the form it needs to invalidate and/or repaint your form or parent control. In you application you are doing too much. You need to Process(Windows)Messages. You can put a WND_MESSAGE loop on your form this is similar to Application.DoEvents.

Comment: @enigmativity Would it have been better if I had highlighted please put busy "painting into a thread", outside of the main thread. Do you want to explain threading concepts to a situation where labels are being moved about on a timer with little breathing room? I did mention best practices.

Comment: It would have been better if you didn't mention `DoEvents` at all. Or maybe even said don't use `DoEvents`.

Comment: I removed DoEvents. I agree it is not a fix.